# hook_form being called twice

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

hook_form being called twice

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form_state['redirect'] = false;
    my_function();      
  }
}
```

my_function() calls twice and I need only one.

I read this post:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22881/hook-form-being-called-twice

And I try use $form_state['redirect'] = false but don't work forme.

Anyone know any clean way to do it? Thanks

Comment: I had this problem before, can't remember the exact thing I did. But if you print the form object, you will see an array of form_validate and an array of form_submit callbacks, you just need to make sure there is only one callback for the form_submit function.

Comment: How I can see the contents of form in each of the separate calls?, sorry my english and thaks for answer :)

Comment: It's supposed to be called twice...`hook_form_alter()` is invoked whenever the form is built, and the form is built both on display and validation/submission

Comment: do dsm($form) within the code shown there. And do print_r($form); exit; within the validation/submittion code.

Comment: form_alter is just to alter forms. if you use it to add Javascript (you still can use #attached though) and/or to call arbitrary functions, you will get an unexpected behavior. You can have same form in the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you should be doing whatever it is you doing in your own submit function.

Add your own submit function by adding your function name to the submit array in your form_alter.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_submit_function';    
  }
}

function MYMODULE_submit_function(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = false;
  my_function(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Drupal comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3078275#comment-13242289):

> Form alter hooks are executed when the form first loads then when it
> is rebuilt during the page request.
>
> I recommend using `$form_state->isRebuilding()` to determine if the
> form is being rebuilt.

This is a pretty simple solution, and it works for me in Drupal 9.

In Drupal 7, it'd probably be:

```php
if ($form_state['rebuild']) {
  // ...
}
```